# How to get info window to pop up when user clicks on the marker?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have the following code that displays markers around a certain area and I want to have an info window pop up when the marker is clicked on. Currently, all the markers refresh when clicked on and the info window does not pop up. How can I change my code for the info window to pop up and display the name of each marker?

```
const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%'
};

export class MapContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
        selectedPlace : '', 
        isSelected: false 
        }
    }

  onClose = props => {
      this.setState({
        selectedPlace: '',
        isSelected: false
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
      google = {this.props.google}
      zoom = {16}
      style = {mapStyles}
      initialCenter = {
        { lat: 1.296643,
          lng: 103.776398}
        }>
          {data.carpark.map(park =>(
              <Marker
              key = {park.id}
              position = {{
                  lat: park.latitude,
                  lng: park.longitude
              }}
              name = {park.caption}
              onClick={() => {this.setState(
                {selectedPlace: park.caption,
                isSelected: true}
              )}}
              /> 
          ))}
          {this.selectedPlace && (
           <InfoWindow>park details</InfoWindow>   

          ) }

      </Map>    
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide us a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**?

Comment: Can you also provide which google-maps library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide which library you are using?

I successfully implemented this on my code using the `react-google-maps library`. The logic I made involves storing the park.id to a parkid state handler every time the marker is clicked. Then I used a condition that check if the value of parkid state is equal to the park.id.

Here is my [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-withjsonfile-infowindow-pspbum) and below is the snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "react-google-maps";
import data from "./data.json";

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       parkid: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap((props) => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
        defaultZoom={13}
      >
        {data.map((park) => (
          <Marker
            position={{ lat: park.lat, lng: park.lng }}
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({
                parkid: park.id,
              })
            }
          >
            {this.state.parkid === park.id && (
              <InfoWindow
                onCloseClick={this.props.handleCloseCall}
                options={{ maxWidth: 100 }}
              >
                <span>{park.id}</span>
              </InfoWindow>
            )}
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

*Note: To make the sample code work, change the value of `YOUR_API_KEY` in the `index.js` file.*

Answer (score -1):

You try to access `this.selectedPlace` when you probably meant to access `this.state.selectedPlace`:

```
{this.state.selectedPlace && (
    <InfoWindow>park details</InfoWindow>   
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake out. I've made the change and I am still unable to open the infowindow. Any idea what might be the issue?